# What is the name of this "character suddenly has expert knowledge" trope?

Tags: trope

What is this called? The trope where, in some episode, a character suddenly has advanced, expert knowledge in a field that they have never mentioned, especially something almost out of character for them, and especially it is never mentioned again in the series.

The one I just saw that made me think of it:
In [Daria S02E02 "The Daria Hunter"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0772445/) Britney displays expert knowledge in guerrilla combat when they go paintballing, but she is more or less a stereotypical cheerleader ditz in every other episode.

Others:

Community [S01E23 Modern Warfare](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1595996/?ref_=ttep_ep23), [S02E23-24 A Fistfull of Paintballs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1640867/?ref_=ttep_ep23), [For a Few Paintballs More](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1862636/), [S06e11 Modern Espionage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4242896/?ref_=ttep_ep11), where the main characters are all pro-level paintballers, but do nothing paintball related otherwise in the series.

How I met your mother [S02E15 Lucky Penny](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0946316/) where Barney successfully runs a marathon, after having displayed no serious athletic ability other than having sex all the time, and did not ever again for the rest of the series.

Weaker examples:

[House S04e15 House's Head](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1216108/?ref_=ttep_ep15), where Chase, a diagnostician and a surgeon, suddenly becomes an expert hypnotist (not that great of an example since it is still a medical skill)

Simpsons [S04e02 A Streetcar Named Marge](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0701048/?ref_=ttep_ep2) where we find out Flanders is incredibly muscular.

Comment: Also is an Ass Pull trope: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AssPull

Comment: I think the Barney example is kind of off because it was a comedic action that got him into consequences. He later couldn't walk and got stuck going round and round in the subway.

Comment: It's an "inverse Chekov's gun". Yes, I just made that up.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find a globally accepted trope name for it but [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/) has given it a name [Suddenly Always Knew That](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuddenlyAlwaysKnewThat) and Tvtropper always do this trope naming for this kind of things.

> How did a character suddenly acquire a needed skill? By an unrelated
>   previous life experience he never knew would prove so useful,
>   sometimes a [Retcon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Retcon). In other words, the character always had the
>   skill, but [You Didn't Ask](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouDidntAsk).